# @Autowired in WebApplicationContext Spring MVC Tests doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do a test in my spring mvc controller and my applicationContext is always null.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
import spock.unitils.UnitilsSupport

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@UnitilsSupport
@WebAppConfiguration
//@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(loader= ApplicationContextProvider.class)
class TimeSheetControllerIt extends TestsSupport {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext; //NULL

    //private MockHttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest;
    private MockMvc mockMvc
    private ResultActions resultActions

    def setup(){
        //this.mockHttpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
```

What must I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try with providing a Context Configuration (the @ContextConfiguration you have commented).

Check the log to see if your application context is properly initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any context configlocation. So, spring does not location of files, from which it can create beans and inject wherever  required.

Remember, context config locations for main application and testing are different. So, even if you have specified it in web.xml, it's scope does not include testing.You will have to explicitly specify it in your test class.